# Code adding \n and 1, and I don't know why

Tags: c++, loops

This is a bit complicated, but basically I'm making a program and one of my functions is acting a bit strange.  The function is fed an array of characters, the first time it's

**new_sensor_node   SN42   42   3.57   5.0   7.**

right now the function just prints out each individual "token" (each set of characters separated by spaces).  Then prints a space, and then prints the number of characters in the token.  But for some reason, the last token is always printed weird, and 1 character extra is counted.

Here's the function:

```
int parseCommandLine(char cline[], char *tklist[]){
    int i;
    int length;
    int count = 0; //counts number of tokens
    int toklength = 0; //counts the length of each token
    length = strlen(cline);

    for (i=0; i < length; i++) {   //go to first character of each token

        if (((cline[i] != ' ' && cline[i-1]==' ') || i == 0)&& cline[i]!= '"') {

            while ((cline[i]!=' ')&& (cline[i] != '\0')){
                toklength++;
                cout << cline[i];
                i++;
            }
        cout << " " << toklength << "\n\n";
            cout << "\n";
            toklength = 0;
        count ++;
        }
        if (cline[i] == '"') {
            do {
                i++;
            } while (cline[i]!='"');
            count++;
        }
    }
    //cout << count << "\n";
    return 0;
```

And here's the output (for that first array):

```
new_sensor_node 15


SN42 4


42 2


3.57 4


5.0 3


7.
 3
```

Any thoughts on what could be causing this?  I suspect it might have to do with how I'm dealing with the null character

Comment: You do know about the [`strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) function? It might be helpful here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very likely that the input string actually contains the newline at the end. Depending on how you read the input, it may or may not be in the input. For example, the `fgets` function reads the newline and leaves it in the buffer.

Especially since you don't actually do any actual tokenization or modification of the input string, you just print character by character, this is a very likely scenario.

Comment: Turns out there was a \r at the end of each line, so my code didn't stop before it because it was only looking for '\0' or '\n'.  Thanks!